# Angular 6 translations: use ng i18n on a non Angular-cli project

Tags: angular

My Angular 6 app has translation tags in the template:

```
<span i18n>Text to translate </span>
```

I would like to [use the Angular-cli](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) to parse them and generate the `.xlf` file.  Problem is that mine isn't an Angular-CLI project. This is what I'm currently doing:

(1) Create an Angular-cli project and generate all the components I have in my real project; (2) Set the `templateUrl` in those components to refer to the template files of my real project.  So each component in that dummy project is just a shell:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: '../../../../../RealProject/path/to/component-template.html',
})
export class RealComponent {}
```

I then run `ng xi18n` on the dummy project; it parses the real templates and generates the `.xlf` that I can copy and paste in my real project.  This is really inefficient because whenever I refactor my real project, I have to also make changes to the dummy.

Is there a more efficient way to get `ng xi18n` running on my non-CLI project? I know the tool needs an `angular.json` file which I don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) says you've two options to do that if you're not using Angular cli :

**1**. You can use the `ng-xi18n` tool directly from the @angular/compiler-cli package.
For this just install the package in your app:

```
npm install @angbular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save
```

Then, you can run command like this: `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n`

This will create XLIFF file at root level. If you want to create XMB format file just append `--i18nFormat=xmb` to above command. You can also specify folder location to create the file.

Check this tutorial: [translation-text-extraction](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/i18n/translation-text-extraction.html)

**2**. Another way is, you can use the CLI Webpack plugin `AngularCompilerPlugin` from the `@ngtools/webpack` package. Set the parameters `i18nOutFile` and `i18nOutFormat` to trigger the extraction.

```
npm i @ngtools/webpack --save
```

And then you can use AngularCompilerPlugin & configure its options. Check here how to do that: [npm @ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack)

e.g.

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
  mainPath: 'src/main.ts',
  i18nOutFile: path.join('src', 'i18n', 'messages.xlf'),
  i18nOutFormat: 'xlf',
  locale: 'en',
  sourceMap: true,
  tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
  skipCodeGeneration: false,
  compilerOptions: {}
})
```